# Kannel: how to define "source-addr-npi" and "source-addr-ton" in sendsms URL?

Tags: kannel

I have some problem with Kannel application. To one of SMSC I send messages with alpha, numeric and shortcode sender id. Every type of sender id requires different "source-addr-npi" / "source-addr-ton". I can set it only static in config, so I have created 3 similar config in my *kannel.conf* file with different TON/NPI settings. Supplier was give me below data as correct:

```
alpha: ton = 5, npi = 0
numeric: ton = 1, npi = 1
shortcode: ton = 3, npi = 13
```

3 binds as transceiver with the same login and password, with the same IP address and port. I can send SMS and it works but now, I have another trouble, because when I send SMS via connection1, DLR is returned by SMSC to connection1, 2 or 3 (it's random). Kannel generated error like below:

```
 ERROR: SMPP[SMSC1]: got DLR but could not find message or was not interested in it id<80FA5E7200000002> dst<xxxxxxxx>, type<1>
```

Is it possible to set "source-addr-npi" and "source-addr-ton" values via HTTP request when I'm sending SMS to Kannel from my application as below?

```
~/cgi-bin/sendsms?smsc=aaa&username=bbb&password=ccc&source-addr-npi=1&(...)
```

Supplier says, that he can't do anything by his side. I have found "source-addr-autodetect" parameter but it didn't work because return for shortcode and numeric sender:

```
source-addr-ton = 2
source-addr-npi = 1
```

and my supplier return error code as below:

```
ERROR: SMPP[SMSC1]: SMSC returned error code 0x0000000b (Invalid Destination Address) in response to submit_sm.
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Unfortunately Kannel doesn't support explicit TON and NPI in sendsms API.
You can try to patch Kannel source to support such parameters of course.

Answer (score 0):

Do You know is there any "ready to use" patch for kannel for as You say "explicit TON and NPI in sendsms API"?